# DLL is not getting loaded after the modification

Tags: dll

I have a dll in which some text like myname is present and now i wanted to change it to mynaam. When i open the DLL with notepad in windows i am able to see the myname and i am changing this to mynaam and saving it. But my application is not even loading this dll. As myname and mynaam are having the same size the dll won't corrupt. Please suggest on this it would be a great help for me.  Do i need to use any binary editor or hex editor to do this?

I Observed another thing that i have renamed my original dll to some other name and made this modified dll with the original name. Then the application is still identifying the old DLL even though the name is different. I wonder how windows checks for a library. Please suggest on this also

Thanks StackOverFlow.....

Sunny

Comment: Do *not* edit DLLs with notepad.  They are not text files.  Edit the source code and recompile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to do that but it is possible though. I did something like that once before. You will need to use some good hex editor. The only thing that you can change is string content. The string must be statically allocated within .data section(Global variable or C extenally linkage compiled variable with the contents initially set to some non-empty string). Next try to locate this string content with the HEX editor within your PE binary. After you managed to find it you are free to change the actual string content - just overwrite the old content with a new one. Hint - The length of a new content must not exceed the length of an old one including null terminator. When replacing an old content - don't forget to put null terminator explicitly in the end of a new string. Hint - OVERWRITE content but strongly DON'T ADD some new bytes.

Sincerely yours, Alex.

Comment: Thanx Alex For Your Response.... I Also Wanted to know the DLL loading Behaviour... 

My Observations are as below:  SaveDimpoData.dll  I changed the string using notepad and saved my modified dll with this name and i kept the original dll like SaveDimpoDataOld.dll in the same directory. But still the application is able to pick the SaveDimpoDataOld.dll. That Means Application is not using the DLL Name to load are there factors also involved please help on this.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.hexworkshop.com/

Comment: After Editing the DLL in HEX Editor the application is loading my modified DLL.  Please any one post provide the background on my previous 2 questions

Comment: What exactly were the other two questions?

Comment: How the Platform is able to load the old Dll?  What are the locations it will check for libraries